# How to Store 'Created By' and 'Updated By' with Current User ID in Database Transactions?

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to store all the transactions that occur in the database.

I have succeeded in storing 'created at' and 'updated at' by adding columns in the base

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Models
{
    public class BaseModel : ConfigurationBaseModel
    {
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then overriding the save function.

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (changedEntity.Entity is BaseModel entity)
        {
            switch (changedEntity.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entity.CreatedAt = now;
                    entity.UpdatedAt = null;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedAt).IsModified = false;
                    entity.UpdatedAt = now;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Now I also want to store 'created by' and 'updated by' where I store the current user ID.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Create `UserId` property in your `DbContext` and use it. How to assign this varibale automatically is another question which needs details from where this information is coming. May simple [injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698290/10646316)

Comment: Look at temporal tables: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/temporal-tables), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Entity Framework Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors).

> Entity Framework Core (EF Core) interceptors enable interception, modification, and/or suppression of EF Core operations. This includes low-level database operations such as executing a command, as well as higher-level operations, such as calls to SaveChanges.

[Here is an article](https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/how-to-use-ef-core-interceptors#audit-logging-with-ef-interceptors) which demostrates how you might implement an interceptor for your scenario.