Maintaining State in Blazor Server Application
I have a Blazor server application in which I have a service registered to maintain state as follows:

    public class AppState
    {
        
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }


In program.cs
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AppState>();

In Index.razor in OnInitialized() I set some value in AppState:

    @inject AppState AppState
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
      AppState.UserId = "logged in userid";
    }


I inject this service in components to grab whatever is required from the scoped service.
However, if I do this in a DataService.cs (which is also scoped) and create an instance of ApplicationDbContext:

    public class DataService
    {
      private IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
      private AppState _appState;
      public DataService(IServicesScopeFactory scopeFactory, AppState appState)
      {
         _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
         _appState = appState;
      } 
      
      public async Task<List<Patient>> GetAllPatientsAsync()
      {
        List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = 
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            
            //access the ApplicationDbContext
        }
        return patients;
      }
    
        public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
        {
            public Guid _tenantId;
            AppState _state;
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
                 options, ITenantProvider _tenantProvider, AppState appState)
                : base(options)
            {
                _tenantId = _tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
                _state = appState; //seems a new instance of AppState is provided 
                                                           here...
            }


It seems that AppState is reintialized (inside the newly created ApplicationDbContext) and I do not get the value of userId that I set in Index.razor. It appears to me that when I use ScopeFactory, to create a scope and call ApplicationDbContext from that scope, a new scoped instance of AppState is created.
What is the solution to this? I need the original AppState maintained.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48698290/7902948

you could use the session storage to maintain the state here is the document you could refer:https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ba16f6bb6934842d78c89ab5314f4b56#3-browser-storage-localstoragesessionstorage

I am not sure if I can use session storage from within a service like MyService registered as a scoped service? I can find a lot of examples of its use from razor components, none from a service.

The solution to this problem was removing the scope factory when creating a dbcontext:
using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = 
            scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            
            //access the ApplicationDbContext
        }

I removed the scope factory and used the dbContextFactory like this:
using (var context = _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
{
    
    docs = await context.Doctors.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    

}

And now when I use AppState or any other scoped service from within the ApplicaitonDbContext, I get the existing instance rather than a new one and hence I can get UserId or whatever I stored in AppState or any other service.

You could use the session storage to maintain the state. here is just sample code for your reference:
AppState.cs:
namespace BlazorSessionAppState.Data
{
    public class AppState
    {
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }

}

Index.razor:
@page "/"
@using BlazorSessionAppState.Data
@inject BlazorSessionAppState.Services.SessionStorageService SessionService
<h3>Blazor Server Session Storage Example</h3>
<p>IsAuthenticated: @_appState?.IsAuthenticated</p>
<p>UserId: @_appState?.UserId</p>

<button @onclick="SetAppState">Set State</button>
<button @onclick="GetAppState">Get State</button>

@code {
    private AppState _appState;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _appState = await SessionService.GetAppStateAsync();
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    private async Task SetAppState()
    {
        _appState = new AppState
            {
                IsAuthenticated = true,
                UserId = "TestUser123"
            };
        await SessionService.SaveAppStateAsync(_appState);
    }

    private async Task GetAppState()
    {
        _appState = await SessionService.GetAppStateAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

SessionStorageService.cs:
using BlazorSessionAppState.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace BlazorSessionAppState.Services
{
    public class SessionStorageService
    {
        private readonly ProtectedSessionStorage _sessionStorage;

        public SessionStorageService(ProtectedSessionStorage sessionStorage)
        {
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
        }

        public async Task SaveAppStateAsync(AppState appState)
        {
            await _sessionStorage.SetAsync("AppState", appState);
        }

        public async Task<AppState> GetAppStateAsync()
        {
            var result = await _sessionStorage.GetAsync<AppState>("AppState");
            return result.Success ? result.Value : new AppState();
        }

    }
}

Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<SessionStorageService>(); // Register as Scoped



Here is the document link:
https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ba16f6bb6934842d78c89ab5314f4b56#3-browser-storage-localstoragesessionstorage

This does not work outside of a razor component. For example, if I call the SessionStorageService from AppState service, I get the IJSRuntime not available runtime error.
